# RoR Sample Application for Platform Test

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm evaluating the feasibility of creating an application for my company using Ruby on Rails on Windows.

I don't want to get half way finished and find out that there are major popular components in the RoR ecosystem which don't run on Windows, and have no work around.

Please recommend a popular open source application, like a blog, ecommerce, scientific or other, which I can attempt to run as a test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check out any of the apps in [opensourcerails.com](http://www.opensourcerails.com/)

If you want a big app to test for troubles check Redmine or RefineryCMS.

Comment: Thank you Mauricio. Any sense of which apps are up to speed with Rails3?

Comment: BaseApp2 is not that great for my purposes. Twitter, OpenId,... No built in Auth or password store. I'm looking for something more "enterprisey" or at least a more full blown application, that queues out of process jobs.

Answer (score 1):

you may want to try out Radiant CMS or Refinery CMS or Spree Ecommerce

Answer (score 0):

it seems that [Spree](https://github.com/spree/spree) and [ror-ecommerce](https://github.com/drhenner/ror_ecommerce) are often used as starting point.